# For loop with bitshifts

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, bit

Can anyone explain how does this foor loop works?

`for (bitMask = 0x01; bitMask; bitMask <<= 1)`

This is the first time that I have encountered such a syntax in a for loop and would love to know how the loop would end.

Comment: eventually, that single bit gets shifted off the "top" of the integer and so the value becomes zero, and the loop ends. So it iterates over each bit of the integer, in effect.

Comment: It depends on the type of the variable used. Speculating about what this code does without knowing that is pointless.

Comment: It is either equivalent to `for (bitMask = 1; bitMask != 0; bitMask *= 2)` or has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 6):

I think the **datatype** of bitMask is important here. So considering it as int. Below would be happen.

1. bitMask would be initialized to value 1.
2. Every Iteration would shift the bit value of bitMask by 1 place.
   eg. 1 = 00001(no of bit will be platform dependent. Considering 32
   bit) left shifted by 1 will give 00010 which is equal to value 2
3. This will generate below sequence of value for bitMask.  1,2,4,16,... until the bit having value 1 overflows the 32 bit size.
4. Once over flowed the value becomes Undefined for **int**. and 0 if bitMask is considered **Unsigned Int** as all the bits are zero now. making the condition in for loop false & break.

Simpler readable version:

```
for (bitMask = 1; bitMask != 0; bitMask *= 2)
```

Comment: Item 4 should read as "4. Once overflowed, the value becomes undefined and nobody can tell what happens to the bits."

Comment: It would be better for `bitMask` to have an unsigned integer type to avoid undefined behavior.

Comment: No: if it were `int`, the program has undefined behaviour once it overflows, so that shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 4):

If you got an **unsigned** int32 variable `bitMask`. At the 32nd cycle, its bit representation is

```
10000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Then shift one bit left, it overflows, and only lower 32 bits are kept, so the value becomes 0 and the loop condition becomes false.

```
1 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
↑
this bit is discarded
```

What about if `bitMask` is a **signed** int? Then it's an undefined behavior.

C standard (N2716, 6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators) says:

> The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2^E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in the result type. If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2^E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined

C++ standard (N4713, 8.5.7 Shift operators) says:

> The value of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are zero-filled. If E1 has an unsigned type, the value of the result is E1 × 2^E2, reduced modulo one more than the maximum value representable in
>   the result type. Otherwise, if E1 has a signed type and non-negative value, and E1 × 2^E2 is representable in the corresponding unsigned type of the result type, then that value, converted to the result type, is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

My perspective is never use such kind of loop as we will easily forget this only works for an unsigned integer. Instead, you should use something like following to generate mask for each bit.

```c
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
    int bitMask = 1 << i;
}
```

Comment: The Intel's manual has no bearing here. The C++ standard says that signed overflow is UB.